Can a set have repeated elements?

Let $\;\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{50} X_i = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^n Y_i = T,\;$ where each $X_i$ contains $10$ elements and each $Y_i$ contains $5$ elements. If each element of the set $T$ is an element of exactly $20$ of sets $X_i$’s and exactly $6$ of sets $Y_i$’s, then $n$ is equal to
$$ \text{(a).} \; 15 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{(b).} \; 30 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{(c).} \; 45 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{(d).} \; 50 $$

I saw a solution to this question on the BYJU'S Learning Program website, where they mentioned $n(T)=500$ and "Number of distinct elements in $T$ is $25$". But shouldn't a set contain only distinct elements?
Are the elements in each $X_i$ and $Y_i$ assumed to be distinct? If they are not distinct, then how do we get $n(T) = 50 \cdot 10 = 500$? Where am I getting this wrong?

A set No; a Multiset Yes.

The website you refer to uses n(T) seemingly as the number of elements if you count everything multiple times (although they use the same notation for two different things, once for when taking the union of $X_i$, and once for the union of $Y_i$). This is not standard notation in any way as far as I know.

Don't believe everything you see on a website, Vinay.

Please, avoid the use of images. From How to ask a good question: "The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries. "

@jjagmath I apologize. I don't know how to write complex mathematical expressions in LaTex. For the sake of clarity, I uploaded a picture. I will soon try to replace the picture.

The end result is that if $A = {1}\cup {1}\cup {2}$, you have that $A$ is a two-element set, those two elements being $1$ and $2$ respectively.  Perhaps they might also choose to write $A={1,1,2}$ at which point it is still a two-element set, noting that ${1,1,2}={1,2}$ as far as sets go, just that there was some redundancy with having written $1$ twice.

I will soon try to replace the picture. --- I've edited the question for you, because I think this is a good example of poor mathematical wording that might be useful to have available for others to learn from. Among other things, saying a set contains $10$ elements could mean that there are at least $10$ elements (when the count is important, as it is here, should say something like "contains a total of" or "contains exactly") and there is nothing in the notation or wording that prevents, for example, $X_3 = X_5.$ Also, "the" appears to be missing in two places in the last sentence.

By the way, I tried to save the web page using the WayBack Machine (to avoid the link going bad in the future, which it almost certainly will at some point) and I got this response: "Save Page Now could not capture this URL because it was unreachable."
